# Problems with copying an entity objects with its association

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, clone

I am using MVC with Entity Framework Model-First in my project

I have a Entity `GoalCard` and this entity is associated to another entity `SelectedQuestion`

The association look like this:  `GoalCard 1....Many SelectedQuestion`

What I want to achieve is to duplicate a GoalCard object and its values and also make sure that the association entity gets that aswell.

I have tried most of the stuff deep clone and etc. But I can't get it to work.

I can succesfully copy a `GoalCard` object and add it to my `GoalCard` entity with a new `Id` but I cant get the association entity duplicated.

I have a repository class that retrives a goalcard:

```
 public GoalCard GetGoalCardByID(int id)
    {
        return db.GoalCard.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }
```

In my action method inside my controllor I do following:

```
public ActionResult Template(int id)
{
   var GoalCard = Repository.GetGoalCarddByID(id);
   Repository.CopyGoalCard(GoalCard);
   return View();
}
```

and finally my repository:

```
public GoalCard CopyGoalCard(GoalCard goalcard)
{
  db.Detach(goalcard);
  GoalCard.EntityKey = null;
  db.AddToGoalCard(goalcard);
  db.SaveChanges();
  return goalcard;

}
```

I would appreciate alot if someone could give me an example on how I can make sure the association entities get copying aswell..

Thanks in advance!

-

Comment: You would need to copy each associated entity and reassociate that with your new goalcard

Comment: Could you give me an example on how that works? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this method to also loop through SelectedQuestions:

```
public GoalCard CopyGoalCard(GoalCard goalcard)
{
  db.Detach(goalcard);
  GoalCard.EntityKey = null;
  foreach (SelectedQuestion q in goalCard.SelectedQuestions) {
      db.Detach(q);
      q.Key = null;
      db.AddSelectedQuestion(q);
  }
  db.AddToPlayer(goalcard);
  db.SaveChanges();
  return goalcard;
}
```

Comment: `SelectedQuestion` is a Entity and `SelectedQuestions` is a Navigation property. Will this work? I can't try your example until tomorrow morning.

Comment: You probably need to reassociate the `SelectedQuestion q` with the new goalcard - not 100% sure though